# react-native run-ios Could not connect to development server npm: '7.19.1' and node : 16.6.0, macincloud.com enviorment

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I am using a rdp machine on macincloud.
i am running below commands and failing with "Could not connect to development server"

```
react-native run-ios
```

error:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Could not connect to development server.

Ensure the following:
- Node server is running and available on the same network - run 'npm start' from react-native root
- Node server URL is correctly set in AppDelegate
- WiFi is enabled and connected to the same network as the Node Server

URL: http://103.228.153.185:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.Appui

RCTFatal
__28-[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
__CFRunLoopRun
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
-[UIApplication _run]
UIApplicationMain
main
start
0x0
```

additionally though the debugger connects http://103.228.153.185:8081/debugger-ui/
but in console there is failure with attaching screenshot

[image]

i have also added url in Appdelegate.m

```
return [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://103.228.153.185:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.AppUI"];
```

i have removed the node_module, clear temp directory,started node server with clean cache, did npm install, nothing seems to work.

other enviorment spec:

```
node : 16.6.0
npm version
{
  npm: '7.19.1',
  node: '16.6.0',
  v8: '9.2.230.21-node.18',
  uv: '1.41.0',
  zlib: '1.2.11',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  ares: '1.17.1',
  modules: '93',
  nghttp2: '1.42.0',
  napi: '8',
  llhttp: '6.0.2',
  openssl: '1.1.1k+quic',
  cldr: '39.0',
  icu: '69.1',
  tz: '2021a',
  unicode: '13.0',
  ngtcp2: '0.1.0-DEV',
  nghttp3: '0.1.0-DEV'
}
```

I think this is a environment issue, Any help would be greatly appreciated
Note: app works fine in android

Answer (score 0):

**RCA:**
This is happening because react-native needs watchman to run in ios, at the same time my user in macincloud.com didn't have privilege to access the watchman that is installed in the machine.
I saw the lack of access privilage from the "npm start" start log.

```
                    Welcome to Metro!
              Fast - Scalable - Integrated



To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"

2021-09-17T19:36:21,739: [] while computing sockname: failed to create /usr/local/var/run/watchman/user-state: Permission denied

Watchman:  watchman --no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code=1, signal=null, stderr= 2021-09-17T19:36:21,739: [] while computing sockname: failed to create /usr/local/var/run/watchman/user-state: Permission denied
```

**Solution:**
From the error it was obvious that watchman is installed ,but user name cant access it, So what i did is i copied the folder of watchman to a location that i can access and provided the same path in bashrc. As to how i decided which path is needed to go to bashrc. I checked the installation step of watchman on https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html,
if you see in the mac installation section, they only copy bin and lib like the below command, note:react-native is not concerned about exact location of watchman, all it wants is to access watchman.

```
$ sudo cp bin/* /usr/local/bin
$ sudo cp lib/* /usr/local/lib
```

**Exact steps to follow to make this issue go away in macincloud.com or any machine where you are not root and do not have access privilage**

1. `cd /Users/{place-your-username}/Documents`
2. `mkdir watchman`
3. `cd /usr/local/bin/`
4. `ls -lart|grep watchman`

   lrwxr-xr-x    1 temp  admin        45 Sep 17 23:04 watchman -> ../Cellar/watchman/2021.09.06.00/bin/watchman
   lrwxr-xr-x    1 temp  admin        50 Sep 17 23:04 watchman-diag -> ../Cellar/watchman/2021.09.06.00/bin/watchman-diag
   lrwxr-xr-x    1 temp  admin        50 Sep 17 23:04 watchman-make -> ../Cellar/watchman/2021.09.06.00/bin/watchman-make
   lrwxr-xr-x    1 temp  admin        68 Sep 17 23:04 watchman-replicate-subscription -> ../Cellar/watchman/2021.09.06.00/bin/watchman-replicate-subscription
   lrwxr-xr-x    1 temp  admin        50 Sep 17 23:04 watchman-wait -> ../Cellar/watchman/2021.09.06.00/bin/watchman-wait
   lrwxr-xr-x    1 temp  admin        48 Sep 17 23:04 watchmanctl -> ../Cellar/watchman/2021.09.06.00/bin/watchmanctl

Note: from above you see wathman is present in the machine, for the below command change the version number with respect what you get in the above response

5. `cp -r ../Cellar/watchman/2021.09.06.00/ /Users/{place-your-username}/Documents/watchman`
6. `echo $PATH`
7. bashrc might not be present at all and you have to create it for the first time,its ok

   vi ~/.bashrc
   PATH:/Users/{place-your-username}/Documents/watchman/bin:/Users/{place-your-username}/Documents/watchman/lib:{add-response from above function here or just add $PATH}
8. `source ~/.bashrc`

Now you can start your react machine

Note: This should work all machines where you want access to certain app which you want access to but due to privilege you are blocked